# issue with transcript instruction in Pharo

Tags: pharo

I have downloaded Pharo 6.0 and trying to follow up his famous or "infamous" book Pharo by Example (I call it like that because the books they give at their documentation page is never in syntony with the programming language)

In the book it says to open a playground and put the following instruction:

Transcript show: 'hello world'; cr.

I have selected the instruction and selected Do It, but nothing happens, only appears to press Ctrl+D as a shortcut and nothing more. I suppose that it should appear the Workspace with the message on it, but it is not working.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have skipped a step.

From PBE 5 (http://files.pharo.org/books/updated-pharo-by-example/ )

Section 2.8

> Let us start with some exercises:
>
> 1. Close all open windows within Pharo.
> 2. **Open a Transcript and a Playground/workspace. (The Transcript can be
>      opened from the World > Tools > ... submenu.)**

and then further down the page

> Type the following text into the playground:
>
> `Transcript show: 'hello world'; cr.`

the section also explains what both Transcript and Playground is.

Answer (score 4):

Not near my books, so I don't know if this was missing in PBE or not, but I think it is straight-forward. You have successfully caused the Transcript to show text, but the Transcript isn't visible.  There are three ways to make it so:

- From a playground, type and do the instruction

  ```
   Transcript open
  ```
- From the world menu, select Tools/Transcript
- Use the keyboard shortcut Cmd-OT

Doing so will open the Transcript, which will then reveal the results of the "Transcript show:..."

Hope that helps.

Comment: If on Windows, use Ctrl-O Ctrl-T to open the Transcript.

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents. Be it even a bit late but perhaps it`l help someone somehow.

You can do this way:

```
Transcript
    open;
    show: 'your message';
    cr
```

Or in case you whant to clear the window area before outputing a new content:

```
Transcript
    clear;
    open;
    show: 'your message';
```

Of course you can type this all in one line

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with javascript, transcript is similar to javascript console (actually it is other way around since Smalltalk and Transcript precede javascript and console, but I digress). So like console, you can show stuff to it all day long, but if you would like to see what is in it you have to open it.